# Why Undo Migrations is not working while using flyway in spring boot project?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, database-migration, flyway

I am using Flyway Community Edition 7.1.1 with MySQL 5.5 and I have done some Versioned Migrations. Now I have Used Undo Migration but it is not working properly. Can someone give me proper solution of it?

Comment: "Not working properly" gives no information. I would start with looking for the error you're receiving here. Someone else has probably asked your question before. If not, you can be the first! Be sure to include information like what steps you follow to generate the error, what the error says, and what you've tried to resolve it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`flyway undo` is not supported in the Community edition - see https://flywaydb.org/download